# Best way to check what page you're on in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

## I have

these simple route/URL when I am in a **car** details page

```
http://localhost:8080/car/1
```

I am using vue2; what is the best way to check if I am on a `car` page?

## I normally

would have checked for the first segment of the URL, but I wasn't sure if that is the best future-proof approach.

## Questions

Should I use JS to detect what page I am ?

Should I use Vue functionality to access the router object?

Why would one decide to pick one over another?

Answer (score 3):

You could provide a name for your route inside the `routes` definition like :

```js
 {
      path: '/car/{id}',
      name: 'car',
      component: CarView
    },
```

then access it using `this.$route.name` or you could parse the `this.$route.path` to get the name using String object methods

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, try using: `router.currentRoute.path`, where router is:

```
import Router from "vue-router";

Vue.use(Router);

const routes = [
  { path: "/", component: Home },
  { path: "/test1", component: Test1 },
  { path: "/test2", component: Test2 }
];

const router = new Router({
  routes
});

console.log('Current route: ', router.currentRoute.path);
```